# Why using directive I loose the Material effects?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I'm trying to understand what exactly is happening.

I had a form with Angular Material, something like:

```
<div layout-gt-sm="row">
  <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
    <label>First name</label>
    <input ng-model="user.firstName">
  </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input ng-model="theMax">
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

... with the onfocus and onblur effecs + inputs layout full.

After that working, I change the form to work with **directives** and the form start to be like:

```
<div layout-gt-sm="row" class="core no-padding-bottom">
    <!-- effect working -->
    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
        <md-icon><i class="material-icons">email</i></md-icon>
        <input type="text" name="asd" placeholder="asd">
    </md-input-container>
    <!-- effect not working -->
    <input-test name="name"></input-test>
</div>
```

... directive template:

```
<md-input-container class="md-icon-float md-block" flex-gt-sm md-no-float>
    <md-icon class="material-icons">
        <i class="material-icons">{{ attrs.icon }}</i>
    </md-icon>
    <input
        type="text"
        name="{{ attrs.name }}">
    <div ng-messages="form[attrs.name].$error" role="alert">
        <div ng-message="server">{{ form[attrs.name].$error.serverMessage }}</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
```

... the directive:

```
app.directive('inputTest', function($injector, $q, $location) {
  return {
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      model: '=',
      form: '='
    },
    templateUrl: baseViewPath('directives/form/text.html'),
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $scope.attrs = $attrs;
      $scope.mask = function() {
        if(typeof $attrs.mask !== 'undefined') {
          return $attrs.mask;
        }
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Now, the form is working 50%, where is been send and validate as well but there's no Material effects and no full fields on screen.

What could that be?

**UPDATE**

I think that I "fixed" changing the *placeholder* to *label*

```
<label>{{ attrs.placeholder }}</label>
```

Comment: I think you need to remove `replace:true` to get rid of your problem. If it will work, ill post it as answer

Comment: I've already tried, but same problem. I'm starting to think that is the way I use ```placeholder="{{ attrs.placeholder }}"```, if I change the value ```placeholder="label test"``` it works.

Comment: take ng-messages out of your input container wrapp the entire thing in a div and put it outside of the inout container

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon, yes... updated.

Comment: @Pablo  take ng-messages out of your input container wrapp the entire thing in a div and put it outside of the inout container